# Recursive for find shortest path using DFS in maze in java

Tags: java, recursion, path, microsoft-distributed-file-system, shortest

`I got stack overflow error when using this code. i want it work if we already found the shortest path, then the recursive code will stop. the maze is contain character '#' and ' '. and if i found the shortest path, the path will mark with '.' please help thank you.

```
public static int getCoordinateY(String location){ //to get x coordinate
    String y = location.substring(2, 4);
    int coor = (y.charAt(0) - 'Q') * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(y.charAt(1));`enter code here`
    return coor;
    }
public boolean canPass(int y,int x) { //you can keep going if you not found # and .
    if(map[y][x] == '#' || map[y][x] == '.' ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public Character[][] cloneArray(Character[][] src) { //copy array
    int length = src.length;
    Character[][] target = new Character[length][src[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(src[i], 0, target[i], 0, src[i].length);
    }
    return target;
}
public void finish(int x,int y){ //goal
    xgoal=x; 
    ygoal=y;
}
public int getDistance(){ //shortest distance from shortest path
    return finalDistance;
}
public void shortestPathStart(int xStart,int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd){
    set('S',xStart,yStart); //start coordinate
    finish(xEnd,yEnd);
    shortestPathRec(xStart+1,yStart,0,map);//to right
    shortestPathRec(xStart-1,yStart,0,map);// to left
    shortestPathRec(xStart,yStart+1,0,map);//to up
    shortestPathRec(xStart,yStart-1,0,map);// to down
    map = result; //final map with '.'
    set('F',xEnd,yEnd);
    print();
}
public void shortestPathRec(int x,int y,int step,Character[][] map){
    if(canPass(x,y)){
        step++;
        Character[][] temp = cloneArray(map);
        temp[x][y] = '.'; //in the maze, '.' using for flags
        if(x == xgoal && y == ygoal){//if already found the goal
            hasDone = true;
            finalDistance = step;
            result = temp;
            return;
        }
        if(hasDone==true && finalDistance<step){ //if shortest path is found other path should be in this condition
            return;
        }
        shortestPathRec(x+1,y,step,temp);//calltherecursive again
        shortestPathRec(x-1,y,step,temp);
        shortestPathRec(x,y+1,step,temp);
        shortestPathRec(x,y-1,step,temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get a stack overflow then you are probably recursing too deeply.  For a problem such as this, that probably means you are not correctly detecting and avoiding loops in your path.  Look carefully at your `canPass()` method, which seems intended to help with this, and at your `shortestPathRec()` method.  How might it be that `canPass()` is not preventing you from looping?

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM ANALYSIS**

You fail to guard against physical backtracking: you move to a wall, but instead of backing up in your call stack (undo the last move), you go to the next recursion call and do the *opposite* move -- taking a second useless step instead of backing up to 0 useless steps.  Your code will infinitely walk between those two squares until you exceed the stack limit.

**REPAIR**

Madify your code so that you never walk to a square you've already visited on this path.  This is easy enough to research on line; Dijkstra's Algorithm is one of the earliest general solutions.

**AVOIDANCE**

Learn basic debugging.  Among other things, insert **print** statements at entry and exit to each routine, printing the input parameters and return values.  For extra clarity, keep an depth counter and indent the prints appropriately.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. i'm trying to make backtrack but failed. can you give me an example to backtrack? I'm confuse with Dijkstra's Algorithm.

Comment: There are thousands of examples on the Internet.  Exactly how and where are you confused?

Comment: Also, please remember the Stack Overflow guidelines.  Among other things, this is a site for *specific* programming questions.  When this gets to "I don't understand backtracking", you need research and a perhaps a local tutor, not SO.